# xorg.conf renders display larger than screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, kde, nvidia-graphics-card

## Background

I am driving a 3-screen setup with 2 1080p screens one above the other and a flanking 1680x1050 in portrait.

## Problem

On boot, the portrait screen is not rendered at the correct height. Instead it displays an image [2432px tall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViS2y.png). Moving the mouse to the edges of the screen causes it to scroll within this large image. This problem occurs both when the resolution of the screen is set to `auto` and when it is explicitly set to `1680x1050`.

If after boot, I change the orientation to a different value hit apply, revert it back to `rotate 90` and apply again the [problem is resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3JlU.png).

If the xorg.conf is resaved with the screen set up in landscape the computer loads appropriately.

## Clues

When I click the `Save to X Configuration File` in the nvidia settings I get the following dialogs.

> Multiple X screens are set to use absolute positioning.  Though it is valid to do so, one or more X screens may be (or may become) unreachable due to overlapping and/or dead space.  It is recommended to only use absolute positioning for the first X screen, and relative positioning for all subsequent X screens.

I am experiencing no dead space. I was unable to find a way to set the portrait monitor to relative positioning, though it was easy to set it up for the secondary 1080p screen (the top one).

> Truncate the MetaMode list?
>
> Long MetaMode strings (greater than 900 characters) are not
>   supported by the current X server.  Truncating the MetaMode
>   list, so that the MetaMode string fits within 900 characters,
>   will cause only the first 28 MetaModes to be written to the X
>   configuration file.
>
> NOTE: Writing all the MetaModes to the X Configuration
>   file may result in parse errors and failing to start the
>   X server.

My options are to `truncate metamodes` or `write all metamodes`. I choose to `write all metamodes`. This seems like the most likely cause of my problems, but I was unable to turn up any solution with google. The following is my xorg.conf

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 319.60  (buildd@komainu)  Wed Oct  2 15:12:10 UTC 2013


Section "ServerLayout"

# Removed Option "Xinerama" "0"
Identifier     "Layout0"
Screen      0  "Screen0" 1050 1080
Screen      1  "Screen1" 1050 0
Screen      2  "Screen2" 0 480
InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

# generated from default
Identifier     "Mouse0"
Driver         "mouse"
Option         "Protocol" "auto"
Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

# generated from default
Identifier     "Keyboard0"
Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

# HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
Identifier     "Monitor1"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VH236H"
HorizSync       30.0 - 85.0
VertRefresh     55.0 - 75.0
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

# HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
Identifier     "Monitor0"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VH236H"
HorizSync       30.0 - 85.0
VertRefresh     55.0 - 75.0
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier     "Monitor2"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "Acer X193W+"
HorizSync       30.0 - 82.0
VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device1"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "GeForce GTX 460"
BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device0"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "GeForce GTX 460"
BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device2"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "GeForce GT 610"
BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen1"
Device         "Device1"
Monitor        "Monitor1"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "metamodes" "DFP-3: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen0"
Device         "Device0"
Monitor        "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 1680x1050 +0+0; DFP-0: 1440x900 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x1024 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x1024_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1152x864 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768_70 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_72 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_56 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480_72 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480_60 +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {viewportin=1366x768, viewportout=1920x1079+0+0}; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {viewportin=1280x800, viewportout=1728x1080+96+0}; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {viewportin=1280x720}"
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1440x900 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1440x900_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x1024 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x1024_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x960 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x720 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1152x864 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1024x768 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1024x768_70 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1024x768_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600_72 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600_56 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 640x480 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 640x480_72 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 640x480_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=90, viewportin=768x1366, viewportout=1680x944+0+53}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=90, viewportin=800x1280}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=90, viewportout=1680x945+0+52}"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0; 1440x900 +0+0; 1440x900_60 +0+0; 1280x1024 +0+0; 1280x1024_60 +0+0; 1280x960 +0+0; 1280x720 +0+0; 1152x864 +0+0; 1024x768 +0+0; 1024x768_70 +0+0; 1024x768_60 +0+0; 800x600 +0+0; 800x600_72 +0+0; 800x600_60 +0+0; 800x600_56 +0+0; 640x480 +0+0; 640x480_72 +0+0; 640x480_60 +0+0; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {viewportout=1680x945+0+52}"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=270}; 1440x900 +0+0 {rotation=270}; 1440x900_60 +0+0 {rotation=270}; 1280x1024 +0+0 {rotation=270}; 1280x1024_60 +0+0 {rotation=270}; 1280x960 +0+0 {rotation=270}; 1280x720 +0+0 {rotation=270}; 1152x864 +0+0 {rotation=270}; 1024x768 +0+0 {rotation=270}; 1024x768_70 +0+0 {rotation=270}; 1024x768_60 +0+0 {rotation=270}; 800x600 +0+0 {rotation=270}; 800x600_72 +0+0 {rotation=270}; 800x600_60 +0+0 {rotation=270}; 800x600_56 +0+0 {rotation=270}; 640x480 +0+0 {rotation=270}; 640x480_72 +0+0 {rotation=270}; 640x480_60 +0+0 {rotation=270}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=270, viewportout=1680x945+0+52}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=270, viewportin=768x1366, viewportout=1680x944+0+53}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=270, viewportin=800x1280}"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1440x900 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1440x900_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x1024 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x1024_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x960 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x720 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1152x864 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1024x768 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1024x768_70 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1024x768_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600_72 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600_56 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 640x480 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 640x480_72 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 640x480_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=90, viewportout=1680x945+0+52}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1440x900 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1440x900_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x1024 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x1024_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x960 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x720 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1152x864 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1024x768 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1024x768_70 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1024x768_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600_72 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600_56 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 640x480 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 640x480_72 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 640x480_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=90, viewportin=768x1366, viewportout=1680x944+0+53}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=90, viewportin=800x1280}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=90, viewportout=1680x945+0+52}"
Identifier     "Screen2"
Device         "Device2"
Monitor        "Monitor2"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "metamodes" "1680x1050 +0+0 {rotation=90}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1440x900 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1440x900_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x1024 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x1024_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x960 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x720 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1152x864 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1024x768 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1024x768_70 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1024x768_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600_72 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600_56 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 640x480 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 640x480_72 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 640x480_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=90, viewportout=1680x945+0+52}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1440x900 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1440x900_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x1024 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x1024_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x960 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x720 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1152x864 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1024x768 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1024x768_70 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1024x768_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600_72 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600_56 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 640x480 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 640x480_72 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 640x480_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=90, viewportout=1680x945+0+52}; 1440x900 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1440x900_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x1024 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x1024_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x960 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1280x720 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1152x864 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1024x768 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1024x768_70 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 1024x768_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600_72 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 800x600_56 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 640x480 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 640x480_72 +0+0 {rotation=90}; 640x480_60 +0+0 {rotation=90}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=90, viewportin=768x1366, viewportout=1680x944+0+53}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=90, viewportin=800x1280}; nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=90, viewportout=1680x945+0+52}"
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
Option         "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection
```

## Circumstances

- I am using the nvidia proprietary driver.
- This is a clean install of kubuntu 13.10
- The 1080p screens are run off of a GTX 460 and the portrait screen is s run off of a GTX 610.

Comment: that takes me back. I the offsets look wrong in your screens definition.  does your system support randr?